# Is it possible to disassemble Visual FoxPro 9.0 exe file?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro, disassembly

I have a legacy FoxPro exe application.

Source codes are not available (it was written in outsourcing and source codes have been never delivered).

There is a request to write exactly the same application in C# and then develop new features. Requirements are outdated as usual. While we can see what application does on UI, we also want to understand internal logic.

Are there any tools for FoxPro that can do the same as .Net Reflector can do with .NET assemblies?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Putting the legal aspects to one side, there are a number of decompilers for FoxPro, there's a list [on the VFP Wiki](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki%7EVfpDecompilers). [ReFox](http://www.refox.net/) is usually the first choice.

Edit 2022-11-04: the VFP Wiki is currently unavailable - there's a [cache of the page here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160828205510/http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki%7EVfpDecompilers).

Answer (score 4):

There's also a Chinese application called UnFoxAll which seems to be discontinued and for which a determined Google search will yield no results at all, whatsoever.